# Program's back-end is Oracle, how to deploy it

Tags: c#, oracle11g

Is it necessary that the computer at which a c#.net program is to be run should be connected to the developing machine to deploy that program as this program uses oracle database to save user's data items

if yes : then plz explain minimum footprint to install oracle database at each target machine

if no : then how could the target will create and access the oracle database through these 5-7 dll files.

any response will be highly appreciable as I am very uncomfortable being in this confusioin. Thanx all....

Comment: This sounds more like an Oracle deployment issue than C#.  You may be better off posting to a server/DB group - your problem souds a bit broad for SO.

Comment: All your app needs to know is a suitable Connection String. Your installer needs to deploy The Oracle Client dlls. Deploying the DBMS itself is a whole different ball game. Too many variables in your question to even start giving a half decent answer. Presumably Express will do? Adding the cost of a full Oracle deployment to your app means you might as well not bother, no one is going to take you up on that kind offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're mixing two different things. Application deployment vs. IT Requirements. For your app deployment NO, you don't need to be connected with your clients, use instead something like ClickOnce. Now, for your IT Requirements, well, if your client needs to have Oracle then they need to provide the DB.

Are they willing to pay each for a license? If not, why don't you use a Cloud DB Service? Or something light like Oracle Express (which is, free).

Comment: actually i am a newbie in c#.net. Till far i thought that 'as we can use access datatable for back-end and we feel no stress how to deploy it on any target machine as each-n-every system today runs MSOffice and hence MS Access, thus keeping this view in the mind I thought that there will be the same case with oracle database application. I was UNAWARE of the fact that oracle client will fetch and update the database that reside on server. Instead of this fact, I was thinking that oracle client (target machine) will have its own oracle_home or oracle database and will fetch and manipulate it.